# High probability of $\sqrt{\log n}$ degree in random graph

Tags: random-graphs

I’m stuck on a problem I’ve found in a book on random graphs. Appreciate any help:

Let $G_{n,p}$ be a random graph with $p=\frac{c}{n}$ for some positive $c$.
Show that with high probability there is a vertex with degree at least $\sqrt{\log n}$.

Answer (score 0):

A much stronger result is shown in this paper:

*Riordan, Oliver; Selby, Alex*, [**The maximum degree of a random graph**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0963548300004491), Comb. Probab. Comput. 9, No. 6, 549-572 (2000). [ZBL0971.05101](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0971.05101).

Comment: Thank you! 
Although I am trying to solve the question using basic tools (it is suppose to be a relatively simple exercise).

Comment: @NickA.R. Yes, I understand, but I find it is often helpful to know what the "truth" is.